# How can I replicate containers inside docker service when I restart docker daemon?

Tags: docker, percona-xtradb-cluster

I created docker service for the image **percona XtraDB cluster** with 3 replicas using the following command

```
docker service create \
--name mysql-galera \
--replicas 3 \
-p 3306:3306 \
--network mynet \
--env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword \
--env DISCOVERY_SERVICE=10.0.0.2:2379 \
--env XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD=mypassword \
--env CLUSTER_NAME=galera \
perconalab/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.6
```

I had already initialized docker swarm with three machines ( named with mach1, mach2, mach3) and all are joined as managers. And the replicas equally distributed to each of the three machines

When I tried to stop the docker daemon in **mach2**, docker created one more replica container in **mach3**. Again I restarted the docker daemon, **mach3** was still running the two replicas and nothing on **mach2**. I manually removed the container in **mach3** and **mach2** was up with the 3rd replica

What should I do to automatically replicate containers on a restarted docker machine?

Answer (score 1):

I dont't think docker service re balance option is available in docker swarm .....   you can re distribute container by updating service with --force option

```
docker service update mysql-galera --force
```

Comment: This is correct. You want the moving of healthy workloads to be a ops-controlled operation. You should be designing your nodes so that one (or more, depending on your failure requirements) can fail and your performance/resources are still good. Once this is true, rushing to move workloads back to a different node won't be necessary. If you never want more then one replica per node, use global mode when creating the service.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to rebalance your replicaset automatically based on the availability of masters / slave nodes with capacity. However doing this would involve killing healthy containers and rescheduling them.

There is a open issue in docker swarm for this 
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24103

Right now if you want to do this the best way seems to be to scle up / down or create a rollout which will attempt to reschedule the containers in the swarm.

Comment: Can I achieve using the flag --restart-condition? Or will it solve half of this situation?

Comment: Not clear how are you proposing to use it but --restart-condition only defines a restart policy for the container.